# Json to Java Object Conversion for hibernate entity mapping

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, jackson-databind

I am trying to convert my JSONObject object into java objects but continuously getting null values only in my java object. Seeking your suggestions that how can i set my json values as java object so that i can save those java objects in my hibernate entities.
***It would be greate if you could tell me how to create my java POJO according to this json.***

**Below is my json :**

```
{
  "msg": "1 out of 1 Transactions Fetched Successfully",
  "transaction_details": {
    "148042": {
      "firstname": "Navneet",
      "transaction_amount": "11.00",
      "amt": "11.00",
      "Settled_At": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "addedon": "2018-09-26 20:36:25",
      "mode": "CC",
      "card_no": "512345XXXXXX2346",
      "additional_charges": "0.00",
      "error_Message": "NO ERROR",
      "payment_source": "payu",
      "bank_ref_num": "368960",
      "bankcode": "CC",
      "txnid": "148042",
      "unmappedstatus": "captured",
      "udf5": null,
      "mihpayid": "40399371551645689",
      "udf3": null,
      "udf4": null,
      "net_amount_debit": 11,
      "udf1": null,
      "card_type": "MAST",
      "udf2": null,
      "Merchant_UTR": null,
      "field9": " Verification of Secure Hash Failed: E700 -- Approved -- Transaction Successful -- Unable to be determined--E000",
      "error_code": "E000",
      "disc": "0.00",
      "productinfo": "Health",
      "request_id": "",
      "field2": "178707",
      "PG_TYPE": "AXISPG",
      "name_on_card": "Mukesh",
      "status": "success"
    }
  },
  "status": 1
}
```

Here is my java code to convert json String into java objects:

```
 if(response.getStatusCode().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("200")){
                    String responseString = response.getBody();
                    JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseString);
                     output=new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(responseJson);
                     ObjectMapper objectMapper  = new ObjectMapper();
                     objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

                     PayUTransactionMap payutxnmap=objectMapper.readValue(responseString, PayUTransactionMap.class);

                     PayUTransactionMap obj = new Gson().fromJson(output, PayUTransactionMap.class);
                   transaction.setPgBankRefNo(payutxnmap.getBank_ref_num());
                     transaction.setPgTxnRefNo(payutxnmap.getMihpayid());
                     transaction.setPgTxnNo(payutxnmap.getBank_ref_num());
                     transaction.setTxnMode(payutxnmap.getBankcode());
```

Comment: can u share your java class that you want this JSON to set to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above json you need to create 3 java classes :

**class1**

```
private String status;
private String msg;
private Class2 transactionDetails;
```

**Class2**

```
private Class3 transactionparameters;
```

**Class3**

```
public String firstname;
public String transaction_amount;
public String amt;
public String Settled_At;
public String addedon;
     etc etc
```

Now for accessing the objects you can use

class1_Object.getTransactionDetails().getTransactionparameters();

this will fetch you all the details available in 3rd class.

*I hope this will resolve your problem.*

Answer (score 0):

That JSON data can be mapped into 2 classes:

```
class Root {
    int status;
    String msg;
    Map<String, Detail> transaction_details;
}

class Detail {
    String firstname;
    String name_on_card;
    BigDecimal amt;
    // and many more
}
```

Remember, JSON properties are unordered, so you can order the fields in a way that makes more sense.

The JSON for `transaction_details` is a JSON object with dynamic property name, so it needs to be mapped into a Java name-to-value `Map`.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have tried your way but due to this architecture i am unable to finalize my java POJOs for this json. Can you post java POJOs that will be formed for this kind of json architecture .So that i can check wheter i am getting values in my java objects or not..

Comment: @nirmalsharma Those *are* the Java POJOs for your JSON.